# Why is it “for s, r in responses” and not “for r in responses” when we only want to “return r[Ether].src” ? Why is "s" included when we only use "r"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I mean  "responses" returns the result of "srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)" which in this case is the MAC address. And we used it below to return the MAC address from that response. What I don't understand is what "unanswered" returns? Why is it there?

```
    import sys
    import threading

    interface = "eth0"
    target_ip = "172.16.155.137"
    gateway_ip = "172.16.155.2"
    packet_count = 100000
    poisoning = True

    def restore_target(gateway_ip, gateway_mac, target_ip, target_mac):

        print "[*] Restoring target..."
        send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", hwsrc=gateway_mac), count=5)
        send(ARP(op=2, psrc=target_ip, pdst=gateway_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
             hwsrc=target_mac), count=5)

    def get_mac(ip_address):
        responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)

        # return the MAC address from a response
        for s, r in responses:
            return r[Ether].src

       return None
```

Comment: `for` syntax need to coply with `responses` type, you can always `for _, r in responses` if you do not need first element of tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `for r in responses:` won't work because `s` and `r` don't mean anything to Python. When you call the code

```
for s, r in responses:
    r[Ether].src
```

Python is looping through the `responses` collection, each element of which is some container with two elements of its own, and assigning the variable names `s` and `r` to be the first and second of these, respectively.  This process is called unpacking.

If you aren't going to use the first variable at all, you could avoid it being assigned like so:

```
for _, r in responses:
    r[Ether].src
```

Comment: Thank you! @n-Holmes ! What about above, why is it " responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10) " and not " responses = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10) " ?  
"responses" returns the result of "srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)" doesnt it? which in this case is the MAC address. And we used it below to return the MAC address from that response. What I don't understand is what "unanswered" returns? Why is it there?

Comment: It's the same thing, `responses` in the given code will be assigned to `srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)[0]` (the first element of a collection, whilst unanswered will be the second).